# Facebook Login with Javascript & PHP

Tags: javascript, php, facebook, cookies

I've been trying to fix this for couple of days now, but can't seem to understand what I've done wrong. The idea is to make the users login using Javascript and do a re-verification through PHP before entering the user's information in the database, but it keeps saying "No cookie set or no OAuth data could be obtained from cookie."

index.php:

```
    var appLoginFlag = false;
    var appAccessToken = null;

    window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
        FB.init({
            appId: 'xxxxxxxxx',
            cookie: true,
            status: true,
            xfbml: true,
            oauth: true,
            version: 'v2.2'
        });

        checkLoginState();
    };

    function statusChangeCallback(response) {
        if (response.status === 'connected') {
            appLoginFlag = true;
            if (response.authResponse) {
                console.log(response.authResponse);
                FB.api('/me?fields=id,name,first_name,last_name,email', function(response) {
                    console.log('Email: ' + response.email);
                    console.log('Name: ' + response.name);
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "user_insert.php",
                        success: function(result) {
                            document.getElementById('login-wrap').innerHTML = 'Hi <strong>' + response.first_name + '</strong>!';
                        }
                    });
                });                         
            }
        }
        else {
            console.log(response.status);
            appLoginFlag = false;
        }
    }

    function checkLoginState() {
        FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
            statusChangeCallback(response);
        });
    }

    (function(d, s, id){
        var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
        if (d.getElementById(id)) {
            return;
        }
        js = d.createElement(s);
        js.id = id;
        js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
        fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
    } (document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));

    function FBLogin() {
        FB.login(function(response) {
            FB.api("/me/feed", "post", {message: "Some message"}, statusChangeCallback(response));
        },
        {scope: 'public_profile, email, publish_actions'
        });
    }
```

user_insert.php:

```
<?php session_start();
    require_once __DIR__ . '/facebook-sdk-v5/autoload.php';

    $fb = new Facebook\Facebook([
        'app_id' => 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
        'app_secret' => 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
        'default_graph_version' => 'v2.2',
    ]);

    $helper = $fb->getJavaScriptHelper();

    try {
        $accessToken = $helper->getAccessToken();
    } catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e) {
        echo 'Graph returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
        exit;
    } catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
        echo 'Facebook SDK returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
        exit;
    }

    if (! isset($accessToken)) {
        echo 'No cookie set or no OAuth data could be obtained from cookie.';
        exit;
    }

    echo '<h3>Access Token</h3>';
    var_dump($accessToken->getValue());

    $_SESSION['fb_access_token'] = (string) $accessToken;

    // Now you can redirect to another page and use the
    // access token from $_SESSION['facebook_access_token']

    // instructions to insert into database
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally, got it right. The problem was with the API version. In my Facebook App Dashboard I had V2.4 while I was coding for V2.2